# Why is my code not being logged to the console?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate a number of restaurant bills using an object method, but none of it is being logged to the console at all.

```
calcBills = {
  bills: [42, 48, 124, 180, 268],
  tips: [],
  billsWithTips: [],
  calcTips: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
      if (bills[i] < 50) {
        return bills[i] * 1.2
        billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
        console.log(billsWithTips)
      } else if (bills[i] > 50 && bills[i] < 200) {
        return bills[i] * 1.15
        billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
        console.log(billsWithTips)
      } else {
        return bills[i] * 1.1
        billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
        console.log(billsWithTips)
      }
    }
    console.log(calcTips(bills))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

on the first iteration of the for loop, you are returning before you reach any of the console log statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `return` statements before the `console.log`.  The `return` is causing the code to exit early.

Move your `console.log` before the `return` statements.  Do something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
  if (bills[i] < 50) {
    billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
    console.log(billsWithTips)
    return bills[i] * 1.2
  } else if (bills[i] > 50 && bills[i] < 200) {
    billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
    console.log(billsWithTips)
    return bills[i] * 1.15

  } else {
    billsWithTips.push(bills[i])
    console.log(billsWithTips)
    return bills[i] * 1.1

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your object, you are declaring a function and assigning it to calcTips property; you are not executing that function.
To execute it and see console.log output: `calcBills.calcTips();`

Also your `console.log`s should precede `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, calling `calcBills.calcTips()` would fail because you're accessing variables outside context in the calcTips function. To fix this use `this` which refers to your object.

Answer (score 0):

`return` works like a `break`. When any of the condition is true, first it returns the value, which means JavaScript breaks out of the loop.

You are not seeing anything in the console because all of the variables are empty arrays, but not **undefined**.

Just make sure to put your `returns`'s at the end.

You can also declare a variable and instead of returning the value, assign the value to the varible and then push it to the `billsWithTips` array.